# Is the class of $\omega$-soluble groups a variety?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, universal-algebra, infinite-groups, derived-subgroup

Let’s call a group $G$ $\omega$-soluble if $\bigcap_{i = 1}^{\infty} G^{(i)}$ is trivial. Here $\{G^{(i)}\}_{i = 1}^\infty$ stands for the derived series of the group.

Note, that not all $\omega$-soluble groups are soluble

My question is:

> Is the class of all $\omega$-soluble groups a variety? And if it is, then by what laws can it be defined?

What have I thought on that topic:

To find out whether a class of group is a variety, one have to check, whether it is closed under subgroups, quotients and direct products. This one seems to be… Thus, if I am not mistaken, it is a variety.

The only two questions that remain are:

> Am I mistaken?
>
> If I am not, then what laws is this variety defined with?

Comment: Quotients seem to me to be too much to ask for. I don't have an argument, but I suspect that, say, free groups are $\omega$-soluble. This would force the variety to contain perfect or simple quotients of free groups, a contradiction.

Comment: @RyleeLyman You are correct, free groups are residually soluble, so these groups do not form a variety.  See (for example) [this paper](https://londmathsoc.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1112/plms/s3-7.1.29) by Gruenberg.

Comment: Free groups are even residually nilpotent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. As it was said in the comments $\omega$-soluble groups are not closed under quotients. If they were, it would have implied, that all groups are $\omega$-soluble, because free groups are, however this clearly is not the case (non-abelian simple groups are hit most "simple" counterexample).